# Jenkins Python API returning 500 Error on Request

Tags: python, ssl, testing, jenkins, https

I am trying to reconfigure an xml file for a jenkins job via the following command using the Jenkins Python API:

```
j = jenkins.Jenkins('https:JENKINS_URL', 'username', 'token')
j.job_reconfigure('Job_Name', 'Path_To_Local_config.xml')
```

And I get the error response

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 844, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Server Error for url:https://URL_TO_JENKINS_config.xml
```

I'm thinking that it might be because of the https but I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Have you checked the error log for the jenkins server?

Comment: did you get any solution?